# Java: How to get an enum value to a string?

Tags: java, sql, enums

Say I have an enum which is just

```
public enum testEnum {
    A, B, C, D
}
```

From an SQL database I got a table called DATA in which one can find the values test_a and prg_l. The values of test_a should be in case the values of my enum (A,B,C,D). But how can I save my enum into record to check the sql data?

```
  public void checkIfRecordIsUsed(String record, testEnum test) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    Query dataQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from DATA where test_a = 'A' and prg_l = ?1");
    dataQuery.setParameter(1, record);
    if (dataQuery.getResultStream().findAny().isPresent())
      tablesWithRecords.add("DATA");
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean `test.name()` ?

Comment: Injecting `test.name()` in your query will do it.

Comment: do you mean like this below?

Comment: or how do I add this to my dataQuery?

Comment: @Jolosin See my answer.

Comment: @Benoit thank you is it possible to inject this without defining the testEnum in the constructor? So that I could leave this only with checkIfRecordIsUsed(String record)?

Comment: There is no need for testEnum to be passed as a method parameter - a member variable initialized in constructor will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the enum's value, as a String:

```
    public void checkIfRecordIsUsed(String record, testEnum test) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        Query dataQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from DATA where test_a = ?2 and prg_l = ?1");
        dataQuery.setParameter(1, record);
        dataQuery.setParameter(2, test.name());
        if (dataQuery.getResultStream().findAny().isPresent())
            tablesWithRecords.add("DATA");
    }
```